# Try_files if nginx module returns ngx_declined

Tags: c, nginx

My company's site is server mostly by an Nginx module made in C. We have received a task to make a fallback from the module to PHP, the module returns NGX_DECLINED if it can't connect with some services, the fallback works fine if the uri is the home '/', but if the url is like /XXX/YYYY, nginx tries to find the root/XXX/YYY folder and fails.

I tried to solve this by using try_files with a @rewrite method, but with this directive the module gets totally ignored, I need the try_files to be used only if the module returns NGX_DECLINED, how can I do this??

Here is the location config

```
location ~ ^/(casas|coches|ropa|otros-anuncios)/ {
        #petra is the module name
        petra on;
        petra_conf_file /etc/nginx/petra.cfg;
        petra_tmpl_loc /var/www/vhost/htdocs/app/webroot/petra/listing;
        petra_mobile_tmpl_loc /var/www/vhost/htdocs/app/webroot/petra/mobile_listing;
        petra_mobile on;
        custom_url off;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/petra.log;
}
```

More info:

The url is parsed with a custom method to make a search with Sphinxsearch, if Sphinx daemon is down, it returns NGX_DECLINED, if it's up, it injects the search results to some templates and sends the buffer chain with ngx_http_output_filter. The module is called in the NGX_HTTP_CONTENT_PHASE

Ty in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in a rather dirty way...

Before returning NGX_DECLINED, I change the request uri so it points to the framework index.php , this way:

```
void set_url_to_home(ngx_http_petra_request_t* preq)
{
    preq->r->uri.len = 1;
    preq->r->uri.data = (u_char*)"/";
}


/* Handler */
    if(search_client_create_and_init(preq) == NGX_ERROR){
        ndk_request_log_err(r, "petra_mod: unable to create sphinx search client, send the petition to php!");
        set_url_to_home( preq );
        return NGX_DECLINED;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get a wobbly workaround, you should correct your C code, you are likely using the wrong nginx core method.

You need to use [ngx_parse_url](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/251331cd59f780fca94bef334f58a6e311e4ad32/src/core/ngx_inet.c#L525) instead of [ngx_http_map_uri_to_path](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/bb8c0683da773566e09797ef8a4ee00ad1e0f956/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#L2014) - like.

Comment: Not using any of those, the url is parsed with a custom method to make a search with sphinxsearch, if Sphinx is daemon is down, it returns NGX_DECLINED, if it's up, it injects the search results to some templates and sends the buffer chain with ngx_http_output_filter

Comment: Added it to the question